# VueJS - router beforeEach infinite next() issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authentication, vue-router

I'm trying to get my vue-router to remember an entry URL and go there after login. This code works perfectly until the next to last `next()` when it ends up in an infinite loop and I don't know why.

In the code below, where I commented `<----- why infinite loop (?)`, I've also tried `next({ fullPath: url})` but that just goes to "/" even though I check and entryUrl is set to my test entry `/requests`

Example path:

```js
  {
    path: "/requests",
    name: "My Requests",
    component: Requests,
    meta: { requiresAuth: true },
  },
```

beforeEach block:

```js
let entryUrl = null;

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  let locStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));
  let stateStore = state.getters.getUserData;
  let userData = locStorage || stateStore;
  let isAuthenticated = userData.token !== "" && userData.token !== undefined;

  // if entry url not "/login" or "/" set entryUrl
  if (to.fullPath !== "/login" && to.fullPath !== "/") {
    entryUrl = to.fullPath;
  }

  // if path requires auth
  if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (!isAuthenticated) {
      // needs auth, none found, send to "/login"
      next({ name: "Login" });
    } else {
      // needs auth, has auth, check for entryUrl
      let url = entryUrl ? entryUrl : "/";
      entryUrl = null;
      next(url); // <-------------------------- why infinite loop (?)
    }
  } else {
    // no auth required ("/login" only in my case)
    next();
  }
});

export default router;
```

By infinite loop I mean it does this until it hits a Maximum call stack size exceeded error. These values are just console logs:

```
auth true
index.js?a18c:150 null
index.js?a18c:152 url /
index.js?a18c:140 auth true
index.js?a18c:150 null
index.js?a18c:152 url /
index.js?a18c:140 auth true
index.js?a18c:150 null
index.js?a18c:152 url /
index.js?a18c:140 auth true
index.js?a18c:150 null
index.js?a18c:152 url /
index.js?a18c:140 auth true
index.js?a18c:150 null
index.js?a18c:152 url /
index.js?a18c:140 auth true
index.js?a18c:150 null
index.js?a18c:152 url /
index.js?a18c:140 auth true
index.js?a18c:150 null
index.js?a18c:152 url /
index.js?a18c:140 auth true
index.js?a18c:150 null
index.js?a18c:152 url /
index.js?a18c:140 auth true
index.js?a18c:150 null
index.js?a18c:152 url /
index.js?a18c:140 auth true
index.js?a18c:150 null
index.js?a18c:152 url /
index.js?a18c:140 auth true
index.js?a18c:150 null
index.js?a18c:152 url /
index.js?a18c:140 auth true
index.js?a18c:150 null
index.js?a18c:152 url /
index.js?a18c:140 auth true
index.js?a18c:150 null
index.js?a18c:152 url /
index.js?a18c:140 auth true
index.js?a18c:150 null
index.js?a18c:152 url /
index.js?a18c:140 auth true
index.js?a18c:150 null
index.js?a18c:152 url /
index.js?a18c:140 auth true
index.js?a18c:150 null
index.js?a18c:152 url /
index.js?a18c:140 auth true
index.js?a18c:150 null
index.js?a18c:152 url /
index.js?a18c:140 auth tru
```

Comment: @Phil the login component sends the user to the root "/" `router.push("/");`

Comment: So that part works ok? Have you debugged the value of `url` yet?

Comment: @Phil yeah -- it logs to whatever entry url I start on so the value of url is correct, i.e. `/whatever/url/that/is/not/login`

Comment: @Phil so it seems ready to go, but if I put url inside the next(url) it goes bonkers (infinite loop).

Comment: @Phil `isAuthenticated = true` after login and `url = "/my-desired-destination"`

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by _"infinite loop"_?

Comment: @Phil added to my original question.

Comment: I got it to work, but get a redirect error: `Error: Redirected from "/login" to "/" via a navigation guard.` -- I can debug that though I think.

Comment: Have you checked if `to.fullPath` matches either '/login' or '/' format?
Because I think it must be a full URL. Try using `to.path` instead